# How to achieve that [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier] returns nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a situation when i need [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier] to return nil (because of reload).
I have called removeAllObjects on my NSMutableArray that holds data for my tableView.

What other datastructure must I clear to achieve my goal (or any other call on tableView)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you elaborate why you have such a requirement? Even if you want to reload the UI content of a cell(s), you don't explicitly want `tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to return nil. You can always customize the `UITableViewCell` that it returns.

Comment: You were right, i was solving the problem from the wrong angle.